# Backup files from an application for which I forgot unlock pattern

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, backup, password

I have forgot unlock pattern for an app on my Galaxy S II. I have emailed the developer but he said he cannot help me.

I am wondering if there is a way I can take backup of the files in the app's folder [ if I can see it :( ] without rooting my phone. There might be some hope of using the data again.

Kindly guide me how can I take the files if this is possible in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Accessing the files in the app's protected storage directory will not be possible without root because you will not have proper permissions to access the directories. If the app saved any data to external storage (SD card, for example) then you can get it, but not knowing the app in question it's hard to say where it would be. Generally speaking it would likely live in `/sdcard/Android/data` somewhere assuming the standard APIs are used, but it doesn't have to use that directory.

Comment: the app in question is `cashdroid`